# C++: Access violation when deleting buffer/pointer after using std::ifstream to read binary file

Tags: c++, memory, binary, fstream

I'm pretty new to C++ and have encountered a problem regarding memory and pointer managment (is what I think). I was trying to figure out how to write and read binary files and managed to scrap together a sample program, however errors keep appearing when I try to tweak it with my own structure.

Heres my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /*  Here is the part which I only ran the first time to write the file
    std::ofstream oFile("foo.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    Data data;
    data.name = "Brian";
    data.age = 32;
    oFile.seekp(0);
    oFile.write((char*)&data, sizeof(Data));
    oFile.close();
    */
    std::ifstream iFile("foo.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    Data* buffer = new Data;
    iFile.read((char*)buffer, sizeof(Data));
    iFile.close();
    std::cout << buffer->name.c_str() << std::endl;
    delete buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine if I ignore the buffer's allocated space, however that'll cause memory leaks won't it? I would appreciate it if anyone would take their time to point out the faults in my code or guide me in the correct direction if my approach is wrong.

Comment: `std::string` isn't writable like you're trying. You need to build a protocol of how you want the data (binary or otherwise) represented on on the stream, then use the `std::string` *methods* to get/set its data appropriately (the "otherwise" is already covered for you, btw). And bin-dumping/loading structures is hideously non-portable anyway, so avoid it in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, it seems a bit out of my grasp, but I take it that I'm completely off the mark?

Answer (score 0):

These statements

```
iFile.read((char*)buffer, sizeof(Data));
//...
std::cout << buffer->name.c_str() << std::endl;
```

has no sense. Class std::string internally uses some pointers to allocated memory. When you read in  your structure data member name has some arbitrary values that do not correspond to actually allocated memory in the program. Your approach of reading binary data is invalid.